# delete duplicated values in multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, duplicates, jupyter

I have a bunch of lists called as follow:
values [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2sxb.png) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2sxb.png)
values [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2sxb.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCSm5.png)
.... until
values[16] [16]

in each list, I have duplicated values that I wanna delete. I was able to do it for only one list (below), I'm looking for a way to do it for all the lists together.

```
values[1][1]= pd.DataFrame(values[1][1], dtype = np.float32)
values[1][1].drop_duplicates('value')
```

Here is the input with the duplicated values and the output
[image]
[image]

Comment: The correct terminology is `Series` as in `pandas.Series`. How are each of these `Series` stored? It looks like 16 different dataframes with one column each? What are the dataframes called?

Comment: values.setdefault(first_int, {})[second_int] = gs.DataFile(os.path.join(folder_path, f))['value']

Comment: each one is an independent list

Comment: so if a number is in one list and another, how do you decide which is the one to survive?